# Newtonsoft Json is not serializing class

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have the following classes that I'm using to collect data and then return the structure in Json.

```
public class Outcome {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string outcome { get; set; }
    public string actionStep { get; set; }
    public List<OutcomeActionResult> actionResults { get; set; }
    public void setData(SqlDataReader reader, DateData dateData) {
        this.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
        this.outcome = Convert.ToString(reader["outcome"]);
        this.actionStep = Convert.ToString(reader["action_step"]);
        this.actionResults = new Outcomes().getActionResultByOutcomeId(this.id, dateData);
    }
}

public class OutcomeActionResult {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string actionResult { get; set; }
    public ActionResultQuestion question { get; set; }
    public void setData(SqlDataReader reader, DateData dateData) {
        this.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
        this.actionResult = Convert.ToString(reader["action_result"]);
        this.question = new Outcomes().getActionResultQuestionByActionResultId(this.id, dateData);
    } 
}

public class ActionResultQuestion {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public bool isMultipleChoice { get; set; }
    public List<MultipleChoiceOption> multipleChoiceOptions { get; set; }
    ActionResultAnswer answer { get; set; }
    public void setData(SqlDataReader reader, DateData dateData) {
        this.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
        this.question = Convert.ToString(reader["question"]);
        this.isMultipleChoice = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["is_multi"]);
        this.answer = new Outcomes().getActionResultAnswersByIdAndDate(this.id, dateData.year, dateData.month, dateData.day, dateData.shiftId);
    }
}

public class ActionResultAnswer {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    public int selectedAnswer { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int shiftId { get; set; }
    public void setData(SqlDataReader reader) {
        this.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
        this.notes = Convert.ToString(reader["notes"]);
        this.employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["employee_id"]);
        this.selectedAnswer = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("selected_answer")) ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(reader["selected_answer"]);
        this.answer = Convert.ToString(reader["answer"]);
        this.year = Convert.ToInt32(reader["year"]);
        this.month = Convert.ToInt32(reader["month"]);
        this.shiftId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["shift_id"]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have Outcome which contains a list of OutcomeActionResults each of which contains an ActionResultQuestion which has an ActionResultAnswer. Something like this:

Outcome -> List(OutcomeActionResult) --> ActionResultQuestion --> ActionResultAnswer

When I step through the code, all the data is being populated correctly and everything is fine.  However, when I serialize the object structure to JSON it serializes everything except the ActionResultAnswer.  Basically the deepest level of the structure gets chopped off.  I've been unable to find anything that tells me why this is happening or how to have it not happen.

Probably ought to put the code that serializes the objects up here:

```
var response = outcomes.getOutcomesByClientAndDate(clientId, year, month, day, shiftId, dayOfWeek);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `answer` property in your `ActionResultQuestion` class is not public.  Therefore, it will not be serialized by Json.Net by default.

You can either make the property public...

```
public ActionResultAnswer answer { get; set; }
```

or, if you intend that it not be public, you can mark it with a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to allow the serializer to "see" it:

```
[JsonProperty]
ActionResultAnswer answer { get; set; }
```

Comment: Holy crap.  How did I miss that?  Thanks.